# Android Java Spotify Mode Remote to search a song

Tags: java, android, spotify

I am new in stack overflow. I am here because I need help with an app I am developing in Android Java with the Spotify Mode Remote to search or better, to find a song.
I'm developing this app in a very naïve way, just to search a song by the name. In my first stage I want to do this (this is my pseudocode...): Main code... imports .... the connection, everything works ok, and now I want to do this: Search("innuendo") for instance.

Everything works ok, but it is impossible for me to find the class and method which opens the search function in the spotify-app-remote. It is mandatory for me to do it using this way (instead the sdk mode that I will do next).
I would be very grateful if anyone can help me.
Thank you very much.

I want to search a song and then play it in the spotify platform that is opened in background.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Spotify App Remote](https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/app-remote-lib/docs/) is like player inside your app. You can just control them. And some other official libraries are just for fun and useless in more cases with android.

In order to use other methods like search you need to use [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api). For example, get wrapper [here](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android) or create API client yourself thought `retrofit` and `okhttp3`. For auth can be used [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) library.